# Change top left title with SuiteBarBrandingElementHtml doesn't work anymore

Tags: branding, suitebar

I am trying to change the top left title with the PowerShell code:

```
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication http://myurlaam                                                               
$webApp.SuiteBarBrandingElementHtml = "My new title"
$webApp.Update()
```

The code works fine with `http://myurl:8019`

It doesn't do anything when I point to my alternate access mapping url.

The code worked some months ago, but not anymore. So now I have for
`http://myurl:8019` a new title but for `http://myurlaam` the previous one.

Could anyone tell me what I should try to change the title?

**EDIT:**
I have tried even this:

- Open IIS  On the left-hand panel open your server, then Sites
- Right click on the site for which you want to change the bindings and
  select ‘Edit Bindings’
- Click Add  Type=http  IP Address=’All    Assigned’ or specific IP 
  Hostname=hostname for your webapplication    e.g. www.contoso.com
- Confirm the changes

, which according to [this article](http://www.informedconsulting.nl/blog/sharepoint2013-suitebarbrandingelementhtml/) should fix it, but no luck